# Use Kotlin multiplatform in Flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to write Kotlin code and call it in Flutter when I run build both in android and ios. Heard kotlin multiplatform can do this, but having a hard time finding tutorials on how to use Kotlin Multiplatform in Flutter.

Comment: Why would you try to do that. Flutter compiles for any device (Android, iOS, Desktop, web, etc). You don't need Kotlin and sharing the business logic of Kotlin multiform will only make your code and performance worst in any possible way

Comment: Thanks for the response. Wanted to test an SDK that's written in Kotlin, so I know I can use it when I build an android application on Flutter. But wondering if I can use Kotlin multiplatform in flutter to make the code work for both. (*New to this :)).

Comment: It's possible to do so however it's not straightforward. The basic idea is:

1) Create your KMP library
2) Compile the library to receive a java artifact as well as ios .framework artifact
3) Create a flutter plugin to wrap each respective artifact and communicate with the java/kotlin library and ios library using platform channels
(https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: We are using this method and once we figured it out it's been pretty useful. As to why: we created an SDK for our company to streamline our app making process. We like using flutter to build our apps, however, we didn't want to create a flutter only SDK as we also have other companies who build apps on our platform. Going this route we are able to ship SDK's to customers who want to build native apps, while we can continue using Flutter. In our case 95% of the code is generated so once the structure was put in place it's very easy to add new features to all platforms.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a go at this method. Can already tell it'll take a while to figure out, but at least I know it's possible!

Answer (score 6):

I've actually started working on a framework which connects Kotlin Multiplatform and Flutter. It really is possible but there's a lot of things to keep track of to get it working smoothly. I published my library a few days ago, try it: https://pub.dev/packages/klutter. Link to a full step-by-step guide is in the readme.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Awesome!! Will definitely check it out. Would be nice if you also did a little Youtube tutorial on it!!!

Comment: The library's name is "klutter", that makes me laugh a bit (: As if combining KMP and Flutter will "klutter" your codebase.